# Setting P-Preferred-Identity in callfile

Tags: asterisk, sip

Is there a way to spawn an extension in a certain context with callfile without originating a call? I have to set my own callerID with the header P-Preferred identity (I cannot use From or anything else).
Of course I cannot add the header AFTER Dial, and I must include in my callfile the following line:

```
Set: __SIPADDHEADER1=P-Preferred-Identity:<wantedNumber>
```

Or adding SipAddHeader in a context before a dial.
So I'm wondering how could I do, since a callfile should spawn a call.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be easily done using local channels.

```
[caller]
exten => 3000,1,Wait(1)
exten => 3000,2,SIPAddHeader(P-Preferred-Identity: <sip:${prefID}@sip.provider.it>)
exten => 3000,3,NoOp(${tocall})
exten => 3000,4,NoOp(${testVar})
exten => 3000,n,Dial(SIP/prov1/${tocall})
```

with the following callfile

```
Channel: Local/3000@caller
MaxRetries: 0
RetryTime: 30
WaitTime: 30
Context: caller
Extension: 3000
Set: tocall=numberToCall
Set: prefID=CallerID
```